# Photoshop Crop not working

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Image content cropped (proprietary).

What i did was:

1. select near the bottom region (to avoid color range affecting main parts of the image)
2. Select > color range > pick bottom edge color > invert selection

It seems like i'm not properly selecting the image with the above steps? Crop has no effect.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you want to achieve? I have a hard time understanding your question, could you please [edit] and clarify? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not certain I understand why you would use Color Range at all.

- Use the **Crop Tool** and move the bottom indicator up to clip the white edge. Then hit the Enter key.
- Draw a Marquee using the **Marquee Tool** which encompasses the top of the image. Then choose `Image > Crop` from the menu.
- Select all, hold down the Option/Alt key and draw a marquee to *remove* the bottom section from the selection. Then choose `Image > Crop` from the menu.